# Could the Actor Ray Winstone Punch a Tethered Horse to Death?

Tags: biology

Due to poor career management and a lack of attention to contractual fine print, the actor Ray Winstone is obliged to punch a horse to death, on camera, in real time.
Ray is a big guy, in good physical shape. The horse can be considered to be in average health, tethered well enough that he cannot retaliate. 
But even without retaliation is it reasonable to expect that Ray could finish the job? What hurdles stand in the way of success? What could Ray do to prepare for the encounter.

Comment: Punch to death, or kill with his bare hands?  Both seem like a morbid use of WorldBuilding, and may actually be more acceptable on Biology, given that the constraints are so physically realistic.  However, there is certainly a big diference if he is obliged to simply hit with his hand as opposed to using other approaches.  For an example of how that could matter, consider Steer Wrestling (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xNyM3mnyXNE), a rodeo sport that is very dependent on the human ability to manpulate the neck of the steer.

Comment: Animal skulls have much more bone and are structurally much tougher than human skulls.  Without any particular special knowledge or research, I have to say that I suspect he'll end up with two completely mangled broken hands and one very angry horse.

Comment: I voted to close, on the grounds that this question is not about worldbuilding.

Comment: Thanks Cort, the punching aspect is important.  And you may be right Jim. Certainly nobody would come out of this well.

Answer (score 3):

No. Ray would be arrested for animal abuse long before the horse died.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely illegal (and rightly so, obviously).

Comment: @DanBennett and he's doing it on live TV, so there's no way I couldn't get caught.

Comment: Any part of a contract that requires the violation of a law is instantly voided null.  Depending on how the contract is set up and the laws of your nation, nullifying one part of said agreement might render the entire agreement invalid.

Comment: Sorry I could have been clearer. The filming is in real time, but not broadcast live. I envision the film circulating in the black market - it would likely struggle to find a distributor. Contract - good point. I suppose it's important for our purposes that Ray be coerced, but not necessarily legally.